# PopUp on Multi POI marker in nutiteq clusters

Tags: android, maps, nutiteq

I'm using Clusters to manage a lot of POIs on my map with Nutiteq. I implemented that base on [this](https://developer.nutiteq.com/guides/clusters) guid. every thing is fine except I have some geoPoint with exact coordinate which they are related to different location entities! I need to show a popUp to inform my user about these points.

Now my question is how to show a popup when user clicked on a multi point marker?

Thank you so much for your attention and participation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You detect Popup data for the points probably using some *metadata* which is attached to the points. Similar to this you should add metadata to the cluster points in your cluster builder. I'm using Nutiteq sample code from https://github.com/nutiteq/hellomap3d-android/blob/master/com.nutiteq.advancedmap3/src/com/nutiteq/advancedmap3/ClusteredGeoJsonActivity.java

1. make sure also ClusterElements have data about individual points. Here I just take all names and put to one long string. You may need something more specific, like list of ID-s

   ```
   @Override
   public VectorElement buildClusterElement(MapPos pos, VectorElementVector elements) {

   // Cluster popup has just a number of cluster elements, and default style
   // You can create here also Marker, Point etc. Point is suggested for big number of objects
   // Note: pos has center of the cluster coordinates

   Log.d(Const.LOG_TAG,"cluster from "+elements.size()+" elements");

   // add all capital names to metadata of cluster element
   StringBuilder capitals = new StringBuilder();

   for (int i=0;i<elements.size();i++){
       capitals.append(elements.get(i).getMetaDataElement("Capital"));
       capitals.append(";");
   }

   BalloonPopup popup = new BalloonPopup(
           pos,
           balloonPopupStyle,
           Long.toString(elements.size()), "");

   popup.setMetaDataElement("ClickText", capitals.toString());
   return popup;
   }
   ```
2. Add MapEventListener to this sample, so you can see the popups for both clusters and individual capitals

   ```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       // MapSampleBaseActivity creates and configures mapView  
       ...
       // listener with vectorlayer for popups
       LocalVectorDataSource vectorDataSource = new LocalVectorDataSource(baseProjection);
       mapView.setMapEventListener(new MyMapEventListener(mapView, vectorDataSource));
       VectorLayer vectorLayer2 = new VectorLayer(vectorDataSource);
       mapView.getLayers().add(vectorLayer2);
       ...
    }
   ```

See sample result:

[image: sample result]